# How do I create a new instance in a factory

Tags: javascript, angularjs, oop, angularjs-factory

I cannot figure out how to create a new instance in my factory.  I created a constructor in the initial factory

```
app.factory('Tea',function(){

var Tea = function(name,description,price,caffeine, size ) {
    this.name = name;
    this.description = description;
    this.price = price;
    this.caffeine = caffeine;
    this.size = size;
}

Tea.prototype.toString = function(){
    var returnString='' ;
    returnString += "name" + this.name + "\n" +
    "description: " + this.description + "\n" +
    "price: " + this.price + "\n" + "caffeine: " + this.caffeine + "\n" + "size: " + this.size;

return returnString
}
return Tea;
})
```

In my next factory I made sure to inject Tea so I would be able to create new instances. I created an object to store my array and created a method to push new instances

```
app.factory("DrinkList",function(Tea){

  var beverageList = {
    drinkLibrary: []
  };

  beverageList.newItem = function(){
    beverageList.drinkLibrary.push(new Tea);
  }
  console.log(beverageList);
  return beverageList;

  })
```

In my controller I made sure to reference both factories that I created.  However, drinkList.newItem is undefined.

```
 app.controller('myController', function($scope,Tea,DrinkList ) {

  $scope.drinkList = DrinkList.newItem();
  console.log(DrinkList.newItem());

});
```

Comment: `DrinkList.newItem()` doesn't return anything. Might suggest you get a better handle on how `ng-model` automatically builds object properties for you before getting too carried away with direction you are on

Comment: You should also read this. People say factories/services are basically the same, which they are, but with what you are trying to do, it does actually matter. I would read up on it. http://tylermcginnis.com/angularjs-factory-vs-service-vs-provider/

Answer (score 0):

I have been working hard to get a better grasp of factories and controllers.

In my Factory I have created an instance

```
app.factory('Drink',function($http) {
var Drink = function(name,description,caffeineLevel) {
    this.name = name;
    this.description = description;
    this.caffeineLevel = caffeineLevel;

}

return Drink;
})
```

This needs some cleaning up, but I realized that I need to use ng-model in my form.   I have declared a form that can be reused and stored it inside of a function.   I am creating new instances each time I click submit.  There is more that I need to learn but this is a start.

```
app.controller('myController', function($scope,Drink,$http  ) {
var init = function() {
     $scope.defaultForm = {
        beverageName: "",
        description: "",
        caffeine: ""
    };
}
init();
// $scope.defaultForm = defaultForm;


$scope.allDrinkList = [];
$scope.drinkList= function(obj) {
    var newdrink = new   
    Drink(obj.beverageName,obj.description,obj.caffeine);
    $scope.allDrinkList.push(newdrink);
    console.log($scope.allDrinkList);
    init();

});
```